# How to add pids at runtime to a top command?

Tags: terminal, process, top

I am trying to monitor a certain process with `top` command and have launched top with

```
top -p <pid1>
```

The process quits after some operations and I relaunch the process. This time the process starts with another `pid`, say *`pid2`*.

Now is there a way to add the *`pid2`* of the new process to the same top running instance? Additionally *`pid1`* may be removed from the top's `pid` filter.

I have formatted the `top` display to suit my need and stopping the `top` and relaunching requires to reconfigure the `top` output each time.

Comment: Configure the output with command line parameters also or use `~/.toprc`.

Comment: @IporSircer Not all implementations of `top` uses a configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `top` with **`pgrep`**. `pgrep` is used to find a PIDs by process name.

```
pgrep sshd
1364
2144
2155
```

Now we got all the PID, it is time to show on **top**:

```
top -p `pgrep -d',' sshd`
```

You can monitor a process by a name with the help of `watch` tool. type:

```
watch -n 5 "top -cbn 1 -p `pgrep -d',' sshd`"
```

to quit press `ctrl-c`. It surely will refresh the top process by 5 seconds.
By using watch command you cannot control the `top` task window.

or you can apply a filter while in `top` task window and type letter `o`, and type `COMMAND=sshd` and press enter.

And howto save `top` config? Just press letter `W`. 
But FYI letter `W` will not save a filter. So you have to apply the filter manually every time you start `top`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I was looking for a way the `top` _automatically_ reloads if one of the _sshd_ process in your example restarts.  I am having a separate console for monitoring where the `top` is running and wanted to keep it undisturbed.

Comment: You can type letter `o` while in task window. and type `COMMAND=sshd` and press `Enter`. I think it should do.